Same Lifestyle of classes but still mismatch error from simpleinjector
I try register collection of implementations but everytime I get error message
"-[Lifestyle Mismatch] ReportFileWriter (Singleton) depends on IFileWriter[] (Transient)."
I dont know what else to try. Please help.
First attempt
 container.Register<IReportFileWriter, ReportFileWriter>(Lifestyle.Singleton);    
 var fileWriters = new List<Type>() { typeof(CsvFileWriter), typeof(XlsFileWriter) };
 container.Collection.Register<IFileWriter>(fileWriters, Lifestyle.Singleton);

Second attempt
container.Register<IReportFileWriter, ReportFileWriter>(Lifestyle.Singleton);        
var fileWriters = new List<Type>() { typeof(CsvFileWriter), typeof(XlsFileWriter) };
container.Collection.Register<IFileWriter>(fileWriters.Select(s=>Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(s, container)));

Third attempt
container.Register<IReportFileWriter, ReportFileWriter>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<CsvFileWriter>(Lifestyle.Singleton); 
container.Register<XlsFileWriter>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
var fileWriters = new List<Type>() { typeof(CsvFileWriter), typeof(XlsFileWriter) };
container.Collection.Register<IFileWriter>(fileWriters, Lifestyle.Singleton);


The source of the issue is described in the Simple Injector documentation:

Warning: In contrast to the collection abstractions, array and List<T> are registered as Transient. Array and List<T> are a mutable types; a consumer can change the contents of such collection. Sharing it (by making it singleton) might cause seemingly unrelated parts of your applications to break when changes are made to it. Because an array and List<T> are concrete types, they can’t function as a stream, causing the elements in the array to get the lifetime of the consuming component. This could cause lifestyle mismatches when the array wasn’t registered as transient. (source)

In other words, arrays are always transient in Simple Injector, even though its elements might all be singletons. Just consider what happens if a class does the following:
public sealed class ReportFileWriter  : IReportFileWriter
{
    private readonly IFileWriter[] writers;

    public ReportFileWriter(IFileWriter[] writers)
    {
        this.writers = writers;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Class thinks it owns the array and changes an element
        this.writers[0] = null;
    }
}

While mutating the array might work as expected within the context of this class, and you could easily unit test its correctness, when such array is shared with other classes (because it's a singleton) it means that this mutation will affect other classes that get injected with this array. They will break in a very confusing way, which will certainly cause debugging headaches. Because a class can change the array at any point in its lifetime, there is no other way for Simple Injector to mitigate this issue, other than giving every consumer its own array copy, in other words making the array transient.
The solution, therefore, is to change the signature of ReportFileWriter's constructor to accept one of the following types:

IEnumerable<T>
ICollection<T>
IList<T>
IReadOnlyCollection<T>
IReadOnlyList<T>
Collection<T>

For instance:
public sealed class ReportFileWriter  : IReportFileWriter
{
    public ReportFileWriter(IEnumerable<IFileWriter> writers)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Unfortunately, the error message you're getting from Simple Injector is too vague, and should be improved.
